# webservice error handling smartface

Tags: android, web-services, smartface.io

I have set-up the web-service for sign up screen and have a error reporting in it when duplicate data is coming. I have successfully sent my data to the web-service and when I send the duplicate data to web-service I am not able to handle that error in the smartface io. I have made tables where the result is stored but `onservererror()` event of webservice I am not able to get any data in it. Help me how to get my error from webservice and confirm about the error to the user.

Comment: I dont know about your service structure, but as I understood you want to see an error when a user tries to sign up with the same informations that another user had already used. For example same name, surname, email  address, etc. Is it true? I guess your error is not a serverError, therefore you can't see it. Is there a parameter that tells you the service did run ok or not? Is it possible to give a link, I will check the parameters of the service you use.

Comment: Yes @mervebıçakçı you are right if same name exist the webservice returns a error. So how can I handle that error and the user should know that Name is there so use another name. It is basically a webservice which stores user data like Name,Mobile Number etc. and also returns a result success or fail. If it returns fail the user should know that error and stay on same page.
Thanks 
Manthan Shah

Comment: You are using a onSyndicationSuccess method right? Inside this method you can check if the success parameter is true or not. Your case should be the case in which the success is false. Server error is different, when you use an invalid parameter or when a timeout occurs, you will see the error in serverError. You can check this link about server error : http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/application-onerror/#server-error

Comment: Hey @mervebıçakçı Help me out please how could I get the response from the web-service that my email and mobile number is not a duplicate on to a label.

Comment: If you could run your service in any other platform such as SOAP or Advanced REST Client or something else, then you can check these documents : http://docs.smartface.io/html/P_SMF_Net_WebClient_responseText.htm and also for more detailed information http://docs.smartface.io/html/AllMembers_T_SMF_Net_WebClient.htm. These should be helpful for you.

Comment: @mervebıçakçı I have gone through this material and I am not getting any text I am getting null value only

Comment: Did you see the response in SOAP or Advanced Rest client, if yes can you share it? I mean the response in duplicate register attempt.

Comment: Yes I did got the response from SOAP that the Email ID you entered already exist but can get the parameter in my app when it executes  it gives a NULL value so I just want to know how can I get 'Email ID you entered already exist' from my SOAP webservice Help me @mervebıçakç

Comment: Which web service did you use? I prefer parse.com and have no problem doing my error checks.

Comment: I am using SOAP webservice and the problem is solved thank you for the reply's.